# Как я могу посмотреть структуру БД своего проекта?

Tags: android, sqlite

Я тестирую свое приложение на реальном устройстве (ноут не тянет виртуальные девайсы), так вот можно ли с помошью adb, например, увидеть какие есть таблицы и содержимое этих таблиц?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам копал в эту тему и, самый простой вариант — это установить `root` права и просматривать базы данных через проводник в Root Explorer (проводник).

Comment: спасибо, думаю это поможет

Comment: @eugeniuskh, способ плохой, но лучший... Вообще я использую эмулятор Genymotion и там смотрю БД. на нем изначально есть root. У меня иногда вопрос: а база вообще создалась? И тут вариант с курсором не прокатывает...

Answer (score 1):

Если БД твоя, можно через Cursor и цикл, вывести по логам в ADB.

Comment: да в том-то и дело, что выводилась ерунда какая-то хотел своими глазками посмотреть